# How to remove shortcuts from Launchpad installed by Windows through Parallels 10?

Tags: macos, windows, parallels-desktop, launchpad

I installed Java in Windows 8.1 through Parallels Desktop 10 and got ugly Java shortcuts in my Launchpad.
I tried to launch "Java configuration tool" right click then remove from Launchpad, but it's still here.

How can I remove it?

[image]

updatetool and Java Control Panel should be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Just found a useful article for my problem: http://kb.parallels.com/112798

1) Open finder, then press Shift+CMD+G and type "~/Applications/"
2) Locate your Virtual Machine's folder (there will be 2 similar folders, click on one that has application icons inside)
3) Remove all necessary shortcuts and they will be gone from Launchpad as well.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your home directory, there should be a folder called `Applications (Parallels)/My Boot Camp Applications`. There, you should find all the shortcuts, you can simply remove them all, or just the ones you do not want to have shown.

Note, I uninstalled Parallels already and just removed the entire `Applications (Parallels)` folder without issues. Unsure if that is still a wise solution when you still have Parallels installed, but just wanted to add that.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to remove items from Launchpad is to click-hold any icon til the icons start to 'dance', then click the X, top left corner.

However, this only appears to be possible for apps downloaded from the App Store. Other apps have no X.

I think the sensible workaround might be similar to how you'd have to achieve it on an iPhone…
Make a new 'folder' by dragging one app on top of another, then use that to keep all your unwanted launch icons tucked away on a screen you don't often visit.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is an old question, but I've just found an page on [Apple Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3189653?start=0&tstart=0). I hope it will help others.