# Parallels desktop keeps creating windows/ubuntu folders in launchpad

Tags: macos, parallels-desktop

When i remove Windows/Ubuntu folder from ~/Applications i am not seeing them in the launchpad.

But whenever i launch parallels desktop - it automatically creates Windows/Ubuntu folders:

[image]

How to prevent parallels from creating these folders again?

EDIT. My question is not about how to delete these folders - question is about how to stop parallels from creating these folders again and again after i launch parallels.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove shortcuts from Launchpad installed by Windows through Parallels 10?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/189778/how-to-remove-shortcuts-from-launchpad-installed-by-windows-through-parallels-10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn the first one off and they won't show up in Launchpad:

[image]